# Compute $(\ln(n!))^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, asymptotics

In a discrete mathematics past paper, I must solve the following problem:

We know (from the Stirling approximation) that $$\ln(n!)=n\ln(n)-n+\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)+\frac{\ln(2\pi)}{2}+\frac{1}{12n}-\frac{1}{360n^3}+\frac{1}{1260n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right).$$ 
Use this information to compute $(ln(n!))^2$ with error $O(ln(n)).$

So, far my working is as follows.
$$\begin{align} 
\ln(n!) & =n\ln(n)-n+\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)+\frac{\ln(2\pi)}{2}+\frac{1}{12n}-\frac{1}{360n^3}+\frac{1}{1260n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right) \\ 
& = n\ln(n)-n+O(\ln(n)) \implies \\
(\ln(n!))^2 & = (n\ln(n))^2-n^2\ln(n)+n\ln(n)\cdot O(\ln(n))-n^2\ln(n)+n^2-n\cdot O(\ln(n))+O(\ln(n))\cdot n\ln(n)-O(\ln(n))\cdot n+O(\ln(n))\cdot O(\ln(n)) \\
& = (n\ln(n))^2+n^2+(O(\ln(n)))^2+2[n\ln(n)\cdot O(\ln(n))-n\cdot O(\ln(n))+n^2\ln(n)]\space\space (*)
\end{align}$$

I think that, in order to solve the problem, I need to determine which terms $t$ of (*) satisfy $t\in O(\ln(n))$.
However, it seems as though none of them do.  Perhaps I have not correctly manipulated the big-O notation.

Could I please have some guidance, in order to make progress with this problem?

Comment: In my opinion, it stands intuitively that, if you want to approximate the result up to $O(\ln n)$, you should start the calcs with an approximation *sharper* than $O(\ln n)$

Comment: Please could you explain exactly why this is so, perhaps with a simple example?

Comment: Because you're making multiplications. Which, in this case, imply the rise of terms in the form $f(n)\cdot O(\ln n)$, where $\lim_n f(n)=+\infty$ obviously, these are not in $O(\ln n)$. This implies that $O(\ln n)$, though closed under addition, is *not closed under multiplication*. For instance
$$n^2+n=n^2+O(n)\\ n^3+n+1=n^3+O(n)$$
$$\left(n^2+n\right)\left(n^3+n+1\right)=\\=n^5+n^2\cdot (n+1)+n\cdot n^3+n\cdot(n+1)=\\=n^5+n^3+n^2+n^4+n^2+O(n)$$

Comment: Another observation giving insight on the issue could be the following:
$$ \begin{cases}n^{1/2}\in o(n)\\ n^{2/3}\in o(n)\end{cases}$$

But $n^{1/2+2/3}\notin O(n)$. On the contrary, $n\in o\left(n^{1/2+2/3}\right)$.

So, for you problem, one must put attention in finding approximations that yield $O(g(n))\cdot O(f(n))\subseteq O(\ln n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Start with

$$\ln(n!)=n\ln(n)-n+\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)+\frac{\ln(2\pi)}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

To see where you want the O-term, you should not that in this case, $O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \cdot n \ln(n)$ gives $O(\ln n)$.

Comment: I will try this now.

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem.

Comment: Okay, well done!